# data prediction using statistics

Tags: statistics, regression, data-analysis, data-mining

Here is the data set for the engagement ratio (ER) of diabetes patients of 11 weeks. How can I anticipate the ER of the 12th week?

[ER in every weeks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA6rC.png)

Weeks           ER

---

1               0.17
2               0.71428
3               0.57142857
4               0.75
5               0.42857143
6               0.85714266                1
7               1
8               1
9               0.2857143
10              0.571428
11              0.5

I would need as many methods as possible for this problem; please feel free to share anything. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm no data scientist, but here's a suggestion. If $\{x_1, \ldots , x_{11}\}$ represents your eleven engagement ratios, define a bivariate data set $\mathbb{D}$ by $$\mathbb{D}=\{(x_{n},x_{n+1})|n=1,\ldots ,10\}$$ Maybe find a line of best fit for $\mathbb{D}$ to predict the ER of the $12^\text{th}$ week using the ER of the $11^\text{th}$ week?

Comment: What model do you have in mind, if any?   Have you looked at the data?  It seems fairly random.  You could, of course, simply compute its mean and standard deviation and use that to make predictions, but of course all that does is to give you a distribution of possible values.